# Adding data from php/mysql query into an XML file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress

I want to add/display data from querying from the database and add it into an XML file.
Example, I have a table_persons which has a name and age. I create a mysql query to get its name and age. Then simply put the data(name and age of persons) into an XML file.

How would you do that? Or is it possible?

Comment: http://php.net/fopen http://php.net/fwrite http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to create your XML file.

Something like this:

```
// Create XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// Create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('persons');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // add node for each row
    $node = $doc->createElement('person');
    $node = $root->appendChild($node);

    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        $columnElement = $doc->createElement($column);
        $columnElement = $node->appendChild($columnElement);

        $columnValue = $doc->createTextNode($value);
        $columnValue = $columnElement->appendChild($columnValue);
    }
}

// Complete XML document
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlContent = $doc->saveXML();

// Save to file
file_put_contents('persons.xml', $xmlContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
[snip] //database code here

$f = fopen('myxml.xml', 'a+');
foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultFromQuery))
{
    $str = "<person>
        <name>{$row['name']}</name>
        <age>{$row['age']}</age>
    </person>\n";
    fwrite($f, $str);
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Assuming you use `mysqli`, this code works. If not, suit to fit. In the `fopen` function call, the `a+` tells it to open it for reading at writing, placing the pointer at the end of the file.

Best of luck.

Comment: You need to escape your values!